# How can I get filter values from a COLUMN rather than a ROW?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, filter

I have two list web parts on my page.

The first list has two columns: user name and ROLE. A user can be listed more than once if they have multiple roles. The view used returns only the roles for the current user.

The second list has two columns, one for role and one for SKILL.

I would like the second list to return all skills which match the roles listed for the user. Currently I can only filter the skills list one role (or row) at a time, SharePoint adds a 'Select' column to the roles list for the user to select which role they want to view. Is there any way to filter the SKILLS list by all roles returned in the ROLES column?

[image: SP Query]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Designer to create a new data source that combines the two lists, then build a Data View Web Part to display the items you want in the order you want and grouped by the criterion you specify.

Comment: Thank you so much teylyn for your quick response. I guess I should have mentioned that I don't have access to SharePoint Designer here :(  Is that the only way this can be achieved?

Comment: If you don't have SharePoint Designer, then the only other option is JavaScript. Doing what you want is possible with JavaScript and/or JQuery, but will require quite a bit of understanding of JS.

Comment: Can you explain more about the two lists: What are the data types of the "Role" field in MyRoles and the "Applicable to Roles" field in the Skills list?